# Multiple Ant properties files

Tags: ant

Ant seems to be ignoring one of my properties files.

```
<property file="local.properties" />
<property file="build.properties" />
```

`build.properties` contains the typical properties my team wants to use. I'm introducing `local.properties` which contains overrides for my specific workstation. We're using Eclipse for this project (I'm using Kepler), but regardless of whether I build in Eclipse or build via the command line the build fails because it is using some values in `build.properties` even though `local.properties` contains overrides.

In my specific case, my version of Java is newer than the other developers/environments. Despite specifying the version I have in `local.properties`, it still tries to use the compiler for the version in `build.properties`.

I know the values are fine because if I put my local properties in `build.properties` everything works.

Comment: Are you sure it's resolving `local.properties` correctly?  Try creating a test script where you just read `local.properties` and see if it is actually able to read it.

Comment: Something like the Java version being used could be affected by external factors such as your machine's environment variables.  How about doing a simpler test and adding something like "debug=local" in local.properties and "debug=build" in build.properties, then echo ${debug} in your script?

Comment: It is reading it correctly, but I figured out what I was missing. Even though the main `build.xml` contains `local.properties`, it builds other `build.xml` files in subdirectories. I thought the properties in the main `build.xml` would carry over, but I guess that's not the case. Do I need to add `local.properties` to all the subsequent `build.xml` files to achieve what I want, or is there another option?

Comment: It depends on how those other files are being used.  If targets are being called within them via the `<ant>` or `<antcall>` tasks with `inheritAll="false"`, then you'll have to load the local properties file individually in each one of them.  If the other `build.xml`s are being imported into your main `build.xml`, then you'll simply need to import them after you've loaded that properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't care about your `build.xml` or your properties files. That's only with Ant.

Try running ant with the `-d` flag, and capture STDOUT and STDERR. This will show you whether or not the `local.proeprties` is being read in and what values are set. It will say whether or not it's attempting to read `local.properties`, whether it found `local.properties`, and if so, what properties are being set.

Also remember that properties are set first come/first serve. You didn't say where in your `build.xml` you're reading in `local.properties`. It could be that this is being read in a target while other properties are set outside of targets. Even if they appear later in the `build.xml` file, properties set outside of any target are set first. If these are set, and you read in `local.properties`, `local.properties` isn't going to over ride them. I mention this because it was a problem I ran into here. Someone had a bunch of `<property/>` tasks placed at the end of their `build.xml`,and they didn't realize that these would be set before any target was run.

Again, try this:

**Unix and Mac**:

```
$ ant -d 2>&1 | tee ant.out   # Allows you to see and capture the results
```

**Windows**

```
$ ant -d > ant.out 2>&1       # There's no "tee" command in Windows.
```

The output of `ant.out` will be thousands of lines long, but it'll help you figure out what's going on. What you post looks correct.